# Laravel in subfolder

Tags: apache, laravel

I am trying to run laravel from a subfolder but my routes are incorrect.

My main page is loading correctly at mysite.co.uk/folder & the login auth works but it redirects me to mysite.co.uk. If I manually navigate to mysite.com/folder it is logged in correctly but all of the routes are messed up.

mysite.com/page is working but mysite.co.uk/folder/page gives me a 500 internal server error.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ folder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**apache.conf**

```
ServerName dev.mysite.co.uk
ServerAlias www.dev.mysite.co.uk
ServerAdmin info@dev.mysite.co.uk
DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/dev.mysite.co.uk/public_html
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/dev.mysite.co.uk/cgi-bin/
Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/dev.mysite.co.uk/stats/
Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/dev.mysite.co.uk/document_errors/
#SuexecUserGroup admin admin
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/dev.mysite.co.uk.bytes bytes
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/dev.mysite.co.uk.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/dev.mysite.co.uk.error.log
<Directory /home/admin/web/dev.mysite.co.uk/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
    SSLRequireSSL
    Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/dev.mysite.co.uk:/home/admin/tmp
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
    php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
</Directory>
<Directory /home/admin/web/dev.mysite.co.uk/stats>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLCertificateFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.dev.mysite.co.uk.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.dev.mysite.co.uk.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.dev.mysite.co.uk.ca

<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RMode config
    RUidGid admin admin
    RGroups www-data
</IfModule>
<IfModule itk.c>
    AssignUserID admin admin
</IfModule>

IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/sapache2.dev.mysite.co.uk.conf*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple change, inside the apache.conf, the

> DocumentRoot

to:

```
/home/admin/web/dev.mysite.co.uk/public_html/folder
```

So you simple set the Root-Directory to the main site and don't need any further modifications.

Comment: that breaks it even more, giving me 500 internal server error for everything.

Comment: Inside the .htaccess you have to set:     `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`